# how to use tinymce to admin custom module in magento2?

Tags: magento2, admin, module, tinymce

I have custom module with custom-template.phtml.

i custom-template.phtml i want use tinymce for tags texarea.

i tried code.

```
 <input type="button" class="action-default scalable" onClick="toggleEditor()" value="Show/Hide editor" />
    <input type='button' onClick='MediabrowserUtility.openDialog(&#39<?php echo $block->getImageUrl()?>target_element_id/custom-html-data&#39)' class='scalable action-default action-add-image plugin' value='Insert Image...' />
    <textarea  rows="15" id="custom-html-data"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleEditor() {
      if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('custom-html-data') == null) {
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "exact",
            elements: "custom-html-data",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_path_location : "bottom",
            extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
            theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : 'true',
            theme_advanced_resizing : 'true',
            apply_source_formatting : 'true',
            convert_urls : 'true',
            force_br_newlines : 'true',
            width : '100%',
            min_width: 0,
            doctype : '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'
               });
      }else{
        tinymce.getInstanceById('custom-html-data').remove();
      }
   }
```

when i insert image it return to textare

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/xam-o1.png"}}" alt="" />
```

but when i click `show/hide editor` url image error.
[image]
[image]

how to use true tinymce editor in magento2 and how to fix it?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is better not to insert that block of code directly into HTML template file, but to use Magento native way to embed field:

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'full_content', 'editor', array(
        'label'    => __('Full Content'),
        'required' => true,
        'config'    => $this->config->getConfig(),
        'name'     => 'full_content',
    )
);
```

To make this work you also need to add dependency into the constructor:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config
 */
protected $config; // <-- add this variable inside the class

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $config, // <-- this new line
    array $data
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    $this->config = $config; // <-- and this new line
}
```